# React not rendering after update state object

Tags: reactjs

I update my state object after changing the value of a `select`. It's setting the correct values to the object, but not updating in the browser (the input fields).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button, Form, Label, Input, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
// More imports

const AddUser = (props) => {
   const propID = props.propID;

   // The object has more properties. I'm just showing the ones related to the issue
   const [ addUser, setAddUer ] = useState({
      unitID: 0,
      adminFee: 0
   });
   const [ units, setUnits ] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
         // this method is an axios request to grab data
         const data = await myAxios.getUnits(propID);
         setUnits(data);
      }
      fetchData();
   }, [propID]);

   const handleUnitChange = async (id) => {
      const unitCharges = await myAxios.getUnitCharges(parseInt(id));
      if(unitCharges !== null) {
         setAddUer ({
            ...addUser,
            unitID: id,
            adminFee: parseFloat(unitCharges.AdminFee).toFixed(2)
         });
       }
   }
   
   // There is a lot of other fields and style here.
   // I'm showing just the related fields
   return (
      <>
         <Label for="unit" className="mr-sm-10">Unit</Label>
         <Input type="select" name="unit" id="unit" 
            value={addUser.unitID} onChange={(e) => handleUnitChange(e.target.value)}
            innerRef={register({ required: true })}
         >
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            {units.map((obj) => {
               return (
                  <option 
                      key={obj.UnitID} 
                      value={obj.UnitID}
                  >
                     {obj.UnitName}
                  </option>
               );
           })}
         </Input>
        <Label for="admin" className="mr-sm-10">Admin</Label>
        <Controller
            as={
                <NumberFormat
                    thousandSeparator={true}
                    prefix={"$"}
                    onValueChange={(v) => {
                        setAddUer({...addUser, adminFee: v.floatValue === undefined ? 0 : v.floatValue})
                    }}
                />
            }
            name="admin"
            id="admin"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={addUser.adminFee}
            getInputRef={register({ required: true })} 
            control={control}
            className="form-control"
        />
      </>
   );
};

export default AddUser;
```

SandBox with array instead of Axios request: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-star-3i9u4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: could you share the source code thru sandbox or similar sharing platform?

Comment: @TopW3 Sure. https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-star-3i9u4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to replace the Controller part of your code with the following code.

```
      <Controller
        name="admin"
        id="admin"
        variant="outlined"
        getInputRef={register({ required: true })}
        control={control}
        className="form-control"
        value={addUser.adminFee}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <NumberFormat
            thousandSeparator={true}
            prefix={"$"}
            value={addUser.adminFee}
            onValueChange={(v) => {
              setAddUer({
                ...addUser,
                adminFee: v.floatValue === undefined ? 0 : v.floatValue
              });
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: In order for a react component to be controllable, you have to set value props to the component, but you didn't specify it in your previous code.

Comment: Got it! Thank you again